# PHP - sorting and merging arrays

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I have a site with a search feature but am trying to improve the search for a fuzzy search.

So far what I've done is query all of my products and use s`imilar_text()` to see how close they are to the actual search term

I then create an array where the key is how similar it is and the value is the product id. I then sort this by the key/similarity.

```
$term = $_GET['search_term'];
$similar_array = [];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM products";
$stmt = DB::run($sql);
while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    $id = $row["pro_id"];
    $result = $row['product'];
    similar_text($term,$result,$similarity);
    $similar_array[$similarity][] = $id;
}
$closest_match = array_keys($similar_array);
rsort($closest_match);
$match_count = count($closest_match);
for($i=0; $i<$match_count; $i++){
    var_dump($similar_array[$closest_match[$i]]);
}
```

This gives me something like:

```
array (size=9)
  0 => int 28
  1 => int 1628
  2 => int 1665
  3 => int 1666
  4 => int 1667
  5 => int 1668
  6 => int 1669
  7 => int 1670
  8 => int 1671
C:\wamp64\www\V2\search.php:65:
array (size=2)
  0 => int 37
  1 => int 38
C:\wamp64\www\V2\search.php:65:
array (size=1)
  0 => int 481
C:\wamp64\www\V2\search.php:65:
array (size=3)
  0 => int 27
  1 => int 1009
  2 => int 1620
C:\wamp64\www\V2\search.php:65:
array (size=14)
  0 => int 30
  1 => int 104
  2 => int 131
  3 => int 134
  4 => int 168
  5 => int 169
  6 => int 170
  7 => int 557
  8 => int 1011
  9 => int 1014
  10 => int 1661
  11 => int 1662
  12 => int 1663
  13 => int 1664
```

I have a `show_products()` function that I just need to pass an array of ID's, so what I want to do now is take the multiple arrays of ID's from above and merge it in this specific order and then crop the array to a certain number so it won't have every product but will cut off after so many results.

Comment: Note that your approach for searching and sorting is going to be very very slow and inefficient as your database grows. Both searching and sorting of records are better done by the database itself than by PHP. It may be more work up-front, but if your database is more than a few dozen records and you want reasonable performance from your system then you'll need to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your query you can use follow below steps

1. you merge all array by `array_merge`
2. sort the array using `rsort` (highest merge come first);
3. for display you can use `array_slice` or `array_chunk`